# PHP Script not working

Tags: php, fatal-error

```
<?php
include("stdio.h");

function main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}

?>
```

Error on line 2?
Dunno what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Funniest SO question I've ever seen.

Comment: Is this a serious question? Could you honestly not find any help on a PHP 'Hello World' script?

Comment: This question is for the win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, your code looks like C code inside a PHP tag.  Here is the PHP equivalent of what you're trying to do:

```
<?php    
printf("Hello World");    
?>
```

However, if you actually did need the main() function, it would look like this:

```
<?php    
function main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
$returnValue = main();

?>
```

This would have the result of echoing the string "Hello World" and setting $returnValue to 0.

Comment: exit(main()); is probably slightly more accurate, but otherwise, +1

Comment: Of course, you're totally right. I was going with the assumption that the asker might want to continue doing something else with the return value of the function.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely C, not PHP. Try

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Comment: Oh you dont need to use a main() function?

Comment: Every installed lib is included by default, and for simple output, use echo. main() doesn't neccesary.

Comment: No.  PHP scripts just run from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The include() statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

So, PHP will try to parse the contents inside stdio.h and since this is likely full of C Code, there will be errors, because that is not what PHP expects to find in there.

Check the [PHP Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 is `include("stdio.h");`. This is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't C.  There is no stdio.h, <s>nor is there printf</s>.  (But echo is usually used if not formatting.)

```
   echo "Hello World";
```

Comment: There is printf http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Comment: Oh yeah!  I'd forgotten that.  Fixing...

Answer (score 0):

The correct PHP equivalent of that pseudo-C program is:

```
Hello World
```

Note: no `<?php` opening tags required.

Comment: I love the fact that someone bothered to downvote this correct answer to a question that is nearly 3 years old. That is *commitment*...

Comment: -1 since the above is *not* PHP code. See [Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) in the manual, which should hopefully clarify the distinction. *\*committed\**

Comment: @salathe But it is a *valid PHP program*. Put the above in a PHP interpreter, out comes the desired output. `T_INLINE_HTML` is a valid PHP syntax token, which is all I'm using here. :P

Comment: An [**animated gif of a kitten snoozing**](http://i.imgur.com/hPzMt.gif) might well be a *valid PHP program* too: that doesn't make it *PHP code*.

Comment: @salathe Arguing over a joke answer on a three year old nonsense question - now that's commitment. :-3 Also, most adorable PHP program ever!

Comment: Animated GIF images of kittens is hardly arguing now, is it? :D